# Does Kubernetes send a signal before restarting a pod?

Tags: kubernetes, undefined-behavior, sigterm

Kubernetes sends a SIGTERM signal to containers in a pod before terminating the pod

Does it send a similar signal when it restarts a pod?

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what you mean here by pod restart. If a pod stops running because an underlying node is lost and then a higher level controller restarts it, then you may/may not see any signal being delivered because it is unexpected termination.

On the other hand, if you're talking about planned termination, where a controller kills/evicts a pod and starts a new pod of the same kind on a (potentially different) node, you will see the same set of events (`SIGTERM -> termination_grace_period > SIGKILL`) occur as in the case of a pod being killed.

Comment: Im my case is a healthcheck fail and k8s restarts the pod... but not sure if the pod received a SIGTERM, as it didn't do a needed cleanup managed by SIGTERM